# Is BKB50 keyboard touchpad for Sony Xperia Z4 compatible with any RDP client?

Tags: keyboard, sony-xperia

As you know - Bluetooth keyboard BKB50 was designed for Sony Xperia Z4 Tablet. The keyboard has an integrated touchpad that controls the mouse on device's screen. With help of some RDP terminal clients I want to connect to my Windows desktop.
Will mentioned keyboard touchpad help to control mouse within RDP session? Which RDP client to use to be able manipulating the mouse by BKB50 keyboard touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Examined with Microsoft RDP client.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the point? Perhaps include a screenshot of it working? Any other RDP clients it is compatible with?

Comment: Unfortunately snapshot will show only Windows desktop (poor proof). Is there any way to attach video to the answer without violating site policy?

Comment: You can link to YouTube, no problem, as long as you attribute it properly. But a proper screenshot is enough.